# R: Assign values to column, from a column from another data frame, based on a condition (different sized data frames)

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I need to create a new column in `df1` named `col_2`, and assign it values from another data frame (`df2`). When the value in `col_1` from `df1` equals a value in `col_a` from `df2`, I want the corresponding value of `col_b` of `df2` assigned to `col_2`.
The data frames are different sizes.

The data:

```
col_1 <- c(23,31,98,76,47,65,23,76,3,47)
col_2 <- NA
df1 <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)

col_a <- c(1:100)
col_b <- c(runif(100,0,1))
df2 <- data.frame(col_a, col_b)
```

I tried the following but none seemed to work... I keep running into the same problem, that the data frames are not of the same length.

```
for (i in 1:10){
   if(df1$col_1[i] == df2$col_a[]){
     df1$col_2[i] == df2$col_b[]
   }
 }

df1$col_2 <- ifelse(df2$col_a %in% df1$col_1, df2$col_b, NA)

df1$col_1[df1$col_1 %in%  df2$col_a] <- df2$col_b[df1$col_1 %in%  df2$col_a]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('col_1' = 'col_a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also use the merge function. It is more useful if you have many columns in the df because you can set all.x = True when you need to keep all the data and not just the merged one:

```
df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "col_1", by.y = "col_a", all.x = TRUE)
```